# Adding new sheet to existing spreadsheet via Google sheets api v4

Tags: java, google-sheets, google-sheets-api

I've been facing an issue within adding a new sheet (tab) to existing spreadsheet.

Before the main issue, I will try to explain why I need to do such a thing and maybe there will be other solution. I'm trying to upload spreadsheet with several sheets. When sheets have smaller size, everything is ok. But when I do the "service.spreadsheets().create(spreadsheet).execute()" request with really big sheets (like two sheets with 40k cells), I get normal response, but created spreadsheet contains only empty "Untitled document" with empty tab. That's first thing which bothers me, why I don't receive something like "your insert is too big" or something like that.

So I would like to create spreadsheet, insert first tab (as a smaller request) and then add another tab (sheet) and so.. But what I only found over the stack and google [documentation](https://developers.google.com/sheets/reference/rest/v4/spreadsheets/request#addsheetrequest) is "BatchUpdateSpreadsheetRequest". But this request doesn't allow me to add already created sheet, it just create new empty sheet, which is really annoying.

Do I miss some API call? Also I found over the documentation and stack some limits, but there is no clear info about how big can be requests with sheets (I've seen all the 400k rows, and what you can found [here](https://support.google.com/drive/answer/37603?hl=en)), but that didn't help a lot.

Can someone provide me info how to "split" spreadsheet creation into creating more smaller request so the created spreadsheet will contain all the data?

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The V4 API currently has a limit of 10MB of data per request, though I don't think we advertise this fact in the documentation anywhere right now.

To workaround, you can use multiple different requests in a BatchUpdateSpreadsheetRequest -- an AddSheetRequest as you mentioned, plus [UpdateCellsRequest](https://developers.google.com/sheets/reference/rest/v4/spreadsheets/request#updatecellsrequest), or some number of other requests.  Check out the [guide](https://developers.google.com/sheets/guides/batchupdate#batch_update_operations) that details what requests deal with what portions of the spreadsheet.

If you have specific portions of the spreadsheet you're curious about how to set, please follow up.

Comment: Thank you Sam for further info about limits.
What bothers me on AddSheetRequest is that I cannot set already created sheet, is it correct? Because what I found is that AddSheetRequest has only set properties or as you mentioned the UpdateCellsRequest - this would mean that I have to do some iterating over sheet and create some specific requests. 
In my case, I have let's say 4 sheets already created (and filled with data). Is there any chance that I will just create spreadsheet which contains one sheet and then call it with the rest:
"AddSheetRequest.setSheet("spreadsheetId, sheets[1])"..?

Comment: I'm don't fully understand the problem, so here's some potential solutions that may or may not apply to your scenario. 1) You can call CreateSpreadsheet to create the archetype (correct number of sheets with the right names, etc.., no data). and then follow up with UpdateCells requests for the sheet IDs from the archetype.

Comment: 2) Call CreateSpreadsheet to create a blank spreadsheet, then follow up with any combination of AddSheetRequest/UpdateCellsRequest to add new sheets & put data into those sheets.  Your AddSheetRequest just sets up the initial properties for the sheet (including an ID), and the subsequent UpdateCellsRequest can reference that same ID.   You can use a DeleteSheetRequest or an UpdateSheetPropertiesRequest to delete or modify the initial sheet from CreateSpreadsheet (always sheet ID 0).

Comment: (I don't completely understand your comment about iterating over sheets, since I don't see why you'd need to ever iterate to do any of this, so I may be missing the point of your question.  If so, please let me know and I'll try to clarify.)

Comment: Well, that's what I wanted to avoid. Because I already have created all sheets with data. What you suggesting is to build them again remotely via small request via UpdateCellsRequest. It seems to me a little bit overcomplicated, when I already have sheets with all the data and I just cannot simply call some method like "spreadsheet.addSheet(sheet1)".. "UpdateCellRequest" solution will mean, that I will need to process created sheets again.

Do you understand what's my point now? There is no other option how to pass sheet object with data to created spreadsheet?